# How can I share a navigation bar among my pages? appengine python Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm banging my head with this one and couldn't find an answer: I want to use the same navigation bar among the pages of my AppEngine Python Jinja2 application.

I tried the tricks below but nothing works, any ideas?

***1) Tried to get the html through through autoescape:***

In Python:

```
include_html = "<h1> Try to insert HTML stuff </h1>"
...
main_template_values = {
    'include_html': include_html,
    }
```

The html template looks like this:

```
...
{{include_html}}
```

And then the actual page displayed in the browser looks like this:

```
<h1> Try to insert HTML stuff </h1>
```

So, instead of big bold text, I get normal texts with visible tags. For some reason the HTML tags are not processed in this way.

***2) Tried Javascript***

I followed the example from w3 schools and created an html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.JS</title>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
<body>
<h1> Testing w3-include:</h1>

<div w3-include-html="included_file.html"></div> 

<script>
w3.includeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then the include_html.html file looks like:

```
<h1> Try to insert HTML stuff </h1>
```

Works if I open the HTML page directly in my browser. However when I use this page as the Jinja2 template it doesn't work. Googlig around it seems that Jinja2 is not compatible with javascript

So,I have more than 10 pages in my application, all sharing the same navbar. This means that for any change to the navbar I have to edit 10 html files, a sure recipe for bugs.

So, how can I include the html code for my navbar into the templates for my pages?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried having your navbar in a separate template, and in the _main_ template adding `{% include 'navbar.html' %}`.

Comment: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#template-inheritance

Comment: @hjpotter92: Thanks man, Jinja2 inheritance is powerful stuff works great! And I also end up with much cleaner html templates for my pages.

Comment: @hjpotter92: Can you post this as an answer, and I will vote it up?

Comment: @kxtronic done.

Comment: @Paco H: works fine, thanks! However, after comparing I prefer to use the tip to use Jinja2 inheritance as it makes for cleaner html files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jinja is a powerful rendering engine. Instead of designing each page individually, you can make use of its [template inheritance](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#template-inheritance) feature.

> The most powerful part of Jinja is template inheritance. Template
>   inheritance allows you to build a base “skeleton” template that
>   contains all the common elements of your site and defines blocks that
>   child templates can override.

So, create a file `navbar.tpl`, containing the bare template of your navbar DOM. Then, create a base template for the application itself, something like `base.html`. In this file, you'd have proper placement of an `{% include 'navbar.tpl' %}`. And create some blocks, for your content placement on the pages your application has.

Now, for each page content, you only have to `{% extends 'base.html' %}` and then override the specific content block you want.

Go through the linked documentation for a better example.

Answer (score 2):

Please try if it works using an `include` statement i.e.

`{% include "navigationbar.html" %}`

Comment: works fine, thanks! However, after comparing I prefer to use the tip to use Jinja2 inheritance as it makes for cleaner html files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is cleaner to use a jinja include.  That way you edit once, and it appears everywhere.

But, the reason your method didn't work is that jinja displayed the tags as text.  To print them as HTML, you would need to do this:

`{{ include_html|safe }}`